# water wave laplace's equation

Tags: calculus, wave-equation

[image]

I have tired differentiating  with respect  to x ,z , and t however I dont seem to be able to show it equals zero.

Comment: I don't think the '$t$' coordinate should be taken as one of those used in the laplacian. i.e. $\Delta=\partial_x^2+\partial_z^2$.

Comment: $\phi$ should satisfy the poisson equation; not the laplace equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\phi(x,y,z|t)$ where $t$ is a fixed parameter for purposes here.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,y,z|t)}{\partial x^2}=-k^2\phi\\\\
&\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,y,z|t)}{\partial y^2}=0\\\\
&\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,y,z|t)}{\partial z^2}=+k^2\phi
\end{align}$$

Then, it is easy to see that

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \phi(x,y,z|t) &=\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,y,z|t)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,y,z|t)}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,y,z|t)}{\partial z^2}\\\\
&-k^2\phi(x,y,z|t)+0+k^2\phi(x,y,z|t)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

which implies that $\phi$ satisfies Laplace's Equation.

---

Note that if $z$ is viewed as a parameter, then $\phi(x,t|z)$ satisfies the one-dimensional wave equation

$$\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,t|z)}{\partial x^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,t|z)}{\partial t^2}=0$$

with $\omega=kc$

Comment: How do you get -k^{2} for the first one?

Comment: $\frac{d\sin x}{dx}=\cos x$ and $\frac{d^2\sin x}{dx^2}=-\sin x$.